# Find node from value in linkedlist

Tags: java, linked-list

I was wondering if there's a way in java to find the position of a node when I have the specific data value as a parameter. For example, if I wanted to remove the node before or after a specific object within the linked list, how would I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Index operations are very inefficient for `LinkedList`, that's why it's better to use `ListIterator`.  Once you find the item you are looking for, it allows you to move in either direction ( that's the main advantage of the `ListIterator` over `Iterator` ).

```
String search = ...;
LinkedList<String> list = ...;

for(
  ListIterator<String> listIter = list.listIterator( );
  listIter.hasNext();
  listIter.next( )
)
{
  String item = listIter.next( );

  if ( item.equals( search ) )
  {
     if (listIter.hasPrevious())
     {
        listIter.previous( );
        listIter.remove( );
        listIter.next( );
     }

     if (listIter.hasNext())
     {
        listIter.next( );
        listIter.remove( );
     }

     break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

java.util.List's `indexOf( Object o )` method is used to find the index of an object. From there, you should be able to remove an object before it using List's `remove(index - 1)`.

Naturally, this is assuming the linked-list you are using implements the java.util.List interface. (This is definitely true for java's built-in linked list.)

Answer (score 1):

You can call `int i = list.indexOf(obj)` to get the index of the object. Then just use `list.remove(i-1)` to remove the previous.

You should add boundary checks so you won't get Exceptions.